# Does removeAllPendingNotificationRequests() cancels local time notifications forever?

Tags: swift, push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications, unusernotificationcenter

I have a time notification in my swift app that sends a push notification locally everyday at 8. I want to add a button so that if it is pressed, it cancels the push notifications for that day only. My question is does `removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()` do the work or will it cancels time notifications forever?

Answer (score 0):

It cancels all the pending notifications that you've registered. In your scenario you could store the `idenfifiers` of the `Notification` that you're registering in a dictionary where the key corresponds to each day which is of type `Date` and the value is an array of `identifiers` which is of type `[String]`. And if you want to cancel all the `Notification` for a particular `Date` you can get the array of `String` identifiers for that date from the above dictionary and cancel them like the following, here's an example:

```
let notificationsDictionary = [Data: [String]]()
guard let notificationsForToday = notificationDictionary[Data()] else { return }
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: notificationsForToday)
```

Comment: but doesn't `removeDeliveredNotifications` remove them after sending the notification? (Delivered ones)

Comment: Sorry about that, an auto-complete mistake. Check now, I've updated it.